# Python 3: How do I get one class to modify values in an instance of another class?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am learning to code in Python and am writing a short program with three classes as practice. The first class uses instances of the second and third classes as attributes. I am trying to get a method in the third class change a value in an instance of itself as well as in an instance of the second class.
So far I have something like this:

```
Class_a():
    self.b_attribute = Class_b()
    self.c_attribute = Class_c()

Class_b():
    self.b_value = 5

Class_c():
    self.c_value = 1

    def change_values():
        self.c_value += 1 

instance = Class_a()
instance.c_attribute.change_values()
```

Calling `instance.c_attribute.change_values()` increases `c_value` for this instance of `Class_a` by 1. Is it possible to write `change_values()` such that calling `instance.c_attribute.change_values()` also changes of `b_value`
this instance of `Class_a`?
If it is possible how would I write that code?

Comment: if you change `Class_c` so you could send `b_attribute` to this class- for example `self.c_attribute = Class_c(self.b_attribute)` then you can change `b_value`

Answer (score 0):

You have a hierarchy on classes of this
Class_a
|         |
Class_b Class_c

now you have done making changes in Class_c and it affects Class_a with regard to the c_attribute component.

This technique is very advanced, and I am surprised you learn it as a beginner.

However, this is accessible only because c is part of a. But notice c is not part of b, and vice versa. See the hierarchy that b and c have no relationship.

A clear way to handle it is to make a general function in a.

But if you want to make a change in attribute_c so that it has a chain effect on attribute_b, you have to set up a trigger in a that can be called by c.

e.g

```
class a():
   def a_change_b(): #trigger function
      self.b_attribute += 1

class c():
   def change_b():
     a_change_b()  #try to call the trigger function outside c but inside a
```

Hope it works.